# I just installed CGAL 4.13: It won't make Triangulation_2

Tags: cgal, ubuntu-18.04

I just downloaded and built CGAL 4.13. It does not "make" Triangulation_2.

To compare, I also remade 4.12, and it "makes" Triangulation_2.

On Ubuntu 18.04 (64).

The issue:
QDomElement: No such file or directory

## include '<'QDomElement'>'

Any suggestions?

Thank you,
Tim

Comment: How exactly did you ask it to "make" Triangulation_2? Was there some cmake command involved (which?)?

Comment: QDomElement is a file in Qt5. You need to install QtXml (see here https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title25 for all the qt dependencies required). Qt5 is required for draw_triangulation_2 examples; other examples are probably correctly compiled.

Comment: Marc: I followed the instructions in the installation page, to cmake, make make install. I think the issue may be that I tried to remove a package-installed version of CGAL. When I removed the libraries using 'apt-get remove', I got the message a several libraries were no longer needed. So, I asked apt-get to remove them. So, I reinstalled CGAL using apt-get, and the error message referenced in my post disappeared.

Comment: Gdamiand: My just-completed comment is relevant to your response. I actually don't know that the explanation I proposed is valid, but 4.13 now makes and I am using the demos and examples.  I will say that I am confused about some of the cmake variable values, and some demos/examples warn about missing code.

Comment: I use 4.13 in order to use the newest stable release/version. The version installed by apt-get seems to be 4.11 - although I modified sources.list in /etc/apt, per guidance on the CGAL support page, in an attempt to have apt-get install the latest stable version (stretch?).